# Manter foco na página principal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Tenho uma página sendo esta minha tela principal, ao selecionar um valor e clicar no botão ele irá chamar outra página referente a que escolhi, a mesma abre em forma de PopUp.

Preciso que esse PopUp abra sem o foco nele, que o foco continue nessa tela principal, pois o sistema trabalha com duas telas e quando perco o foco do principal preciso ficar clicando de volta se quiser executar as operações.

Eu li sobre o `focus();` mas não encontrei algo que me ajudasse com a página, consegui fazer em vários aspectos, aplicando em inputs, buttons e links, mas o que preciso é o foco em toda a página.

Também verifiquei que existe problemas relacionados ao meu documento possuir `$(document).ready(function() {`

Estou postando para saber se posso conseguir uma ideia de como fazer este processo.

Comment: Porque no PopUp vc não cria um evento que joga o foco de volta para pagina Pai usando um link com ancora? Tipo href="../pg-pai.html#ancora"

Comment: Ola, estou gostando da sua ideia, mas, não entendi direito como funciona.. Se eu chamar um iink ele não vai simplesmente reabrir a página? Ainda não tentei pois no momento não estou podendo, mas vou focar nessa ideia sim.

Comment: e no caso também será necessário criar um $(document).ready(function() { para o meu PopUp né?! Com essa função que disse?

Comment: a ideia é essa mesmo. Eu não entendo muito de JS, mas pelo que vejo acredito que isso é possível. No final do load do Popup vc redireciona com um link para a "ancora" da página pai.

Comment: Beleza, folguei agora do trabalho, vou tentar fazer algo relacionado a isso. Quando terminar dou uma resposta.

Comment: Realmente tentei de N formas e não consigo, o máximo que ele faz é redirecionar dentro do próprio popUp.. 

Veja se é isso que imaginou mesmo:

window.location.href="../../Painel.html#ancora" (isso fica num js que é chamado junto ao popUP)

Comment: Alexandre como te falei eu não sou o cara do JS rss.. Tenta editar a sua pergunta com o que tem de JS, ou criar uma nova pergunta com esse JS e o seu problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom dia prezados(as), agradeço aqueles que participaram dando uma ideia ou até apresentando códigos, através de programação foi mais difícil do que pensei e nenhuma das ideias funcionou.
Procurei em vários fóruns e tentei vários tipos de programação. Em resposta a minha dúvida, ao testar pelo navegador Firefox percebi que está funcionando, pois no firefox quem fica em primeiro plano é a página principal e não o popUp.

Provavelmente isso é configuração do navegador, então, caso alguém saiba como mudar a configuração do chrome para que o popUp fique em segundo plano, agradeço.

No mais, a solução está no navegador, em meu caso foi resolvido com o firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Basta utilizar o atributo do html5 `target`

```html
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com" target="_blank">Sem mudar o foco</a><br>

<a href="https://www.w3schools.com" target="_blank">Mudar o foco</a>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela contribuição, mas este caso não resolveu, o blank faz abrir em uma nova guia, show. Este procedimento eu consegui com o popUp a questão é, ele abre em outra página mas preciso que o foco se mantenha na anterior, que ele abra em segundo plano.